# Error in inserting a sobject in batch apex and passing the same object in webservice call

Tags: batch, governorlimits, webservices, callout, scheduled-apex

i need to

- Insert a List of Sobject
- Pass the ID of SObject that has been inserted in to a webservice call.
- This has to be done in Batch Apex since it needs to run on a daily basis.

Now i have done the code but currently getting the error "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out batchapex". I know this error which means that i cannot make a callout since the insert action is still not committed, but i need to pass the ID of the inserted object in the call.I cant use @future methods too since it cannot be called in batch apex. What is the best design you would suggest to overcome this issue

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Program_Enrollment__c> enrollmentList){     
    List<Program_Billing__c> billingList = new List<Program_Billing__c>();
    List<CreateInvoice_WrapperClass.invoice_element> invoiceWrapperList = new List<CreateInvoice_WrapperClass.invoice_element>();

    for(Program_Enrollment__c prog : enrollmentList){
        CreateInvoice_WrapperClass.invoice_element invoiceWrapperObj = new CreateInvoice_WrapperClass.invoice_element();
        invoiceWrapperObj.account = prog.Buyer_Account__r.Group_ID__c;
        invoiceWrapperObj.programId = null;
        invoiceWrapperObj.recordType =  prog.Buyer_Account__r.recordtype.name;
    invoiceWrapperList.add(invoiceWrapperObj);
        Program_Billing__c billingObj = new Program_Billing__c(Status__c='Pending',Sold_To_BP__c=prog.Buyer_Account__c,Program_Enrollment__c=prog.id);
        billingList.add(billingObj);

    }

    if(billingList.size()>0){
        database.Saveresult[] results = database.Insert(billingList,false);

        integer i = 0;
        for(database.Saveresult sr : results){
            if(!sr.isSuccess()){
                Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
                invoiceWrapperList[i].programId = 'Error:'+err.getMessage();
            }
            else
                invoiceWrapperList[i].programId = sr.getid();
            i++;                            
        }
    }  
    system.debug('######'+invoiceWrapperList);
    if(invoiceWrapperList.size()>0){
        CreateInvoice_StubClass.intfwsCreateInvoicesEndpoint1 stubClassObj = new CreateInvoice_StubClass.intfwsCreateInvoicesEndpoint1();
        CreateInvoice_WrapperClass.reply_element responseObj = stubClassObj.CreateInvoicesOp('Subscription for '+system.today(),invoiceWrapperList);
        system.debug('@@@@'+responseObj);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Could you create an external Id field and pass the external Id before the insert that however suffers from a risk of the insert failing. The only other later alternative I can see if marking the records or inserting ids into a dedicated 'queue' object which is polled by another batch job that makes the call out for you. How about using an outbound message to make the callout?

Comment: Maybe take advantage of the new Batch chaining functionality - run the batch to create the Billing List with a flag to say Process, and then execute a batch in the finish to call a second batch that queries for records when flag = Process, sent to web service, and then update Process flag as complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BritsihBoyInDC's post comment is the best approach I can think of.

The first batch creates the records and flags them for further processing.  In the finish method initiate a second batch that queries all records flagged for further processing, do your callout and then uncheck the processing flag.

Prior to the available of chaining batches I'd done a batch that used an iterable to set the number of loops to 2x the number of records to process.  Odd batches created records, Even batches send out the webservice calls.  It worked, but it was a pain.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies...yes i think batch chaining is the way forward..thanks all..